# AutoSuggest from JSON with Link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

Hy!

I want to make a autosuggest from my php file that returns a Json Object.
I parse it in js to get a link with the right id (look at the json)

JSON from search_new.php:

```
{"Data":{"Recipes":{"Recipe_5":{"ID":"5","TITLE":"Spaghetti Bolognese"},"Recipe_7":{"ID":"7","TITLE":"Wurstel"},"Recipe_9":{"ID":"9","TITLE":"Schnitzel"},"Recipe_10":{"ID":"10","TITLE":null},"Recipe_19":{"ID":"19","TITLE":null},"Recipe_20":{"ID":"20","TITLE":"Hundefutter"},"Recipe_26":{"ID":"26","TITLE":"Apfelstrudel"},"Recipe_37":{"ID":"37","TITLE":null},"Recipe_38":{"ID":"38","TITLE":"AENDERUNG"},"Recipe_39":{"ID":"39","TITLE":null},"Recipe_40":{"ID":"40","TITLE":"Schnitzel"},"Recipe_42":{"ID":"42","TITLE":"Release-Test"},"Recipe_43":{"ID":"43","TITLE":"Wurstel2"}}},"Message":null,"Code":200}
```

Calling in JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
   var allRecipes = (<?php include("php/search_new.php"); ?>).Data.Recipes;
      var recipeNames = [];
   for(var i in allRecipes) {
       recipeNames.push("<a href=\"/php/get_recipe_byID.php?id="+ allRecipes[i].ID + "\">" + allRecipes[i].TITLE) + "</a>");
   }
   var arr = new Array();
   for(var k in recipeNames){
   arr.push(" " + recipeNames[k]);
   }

   $("#searchrecipes").autocomplete({
   minLength: 3,
   source: arr 
  }); 
      });
   </script>
```

Firebug Error:

> missing ; before statement recipeNames.push("" +
>   allRecipes[i].TITLE) + "");

Before i had `recipeNames.push("allRecipes[i].TITLE)");` everything worked well

Please help.

Comment: `(` opend once but closed twice

Comment: @run post it as answer. another quest: now it appears as text and not as a href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I see your problem.
Here is the code you need:

```
$(function() {
   var data = (<?php echo file_get_contents("php/search_new.php"); ?>).Data.Recipes;
   var source = [];
   for (var i in data) {
       source.push({"href": "/php/get_recipe_byID.php?id=" + data[i].ID, "label": data[i].TITLE});
   }
   $("#searchrecipes").autocomplete({
      minLength: 3,
      source: source,
      select: function(event, ui) {
          window.location.href = ui.item.href;
      }
  }); 
});
```

You can find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dFApV/

Answer (score 0):

there is for sure an extra bracket right to  allRecipes[i].TITLE that must be erased! :D

I would say, you could achieve the same result, but with a much nicer solution by using the .result method.
Tell me what do you think about it!

[JQuery API Autocomplete Result](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler)

Comment: Is this the plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete? Cause doesn't look like it accepts links... but I'll check further